# Extract text after 2nd “-“ in text with in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to extract text after 2nd “-“ in string

For example
Original text     |   after extract
8L47-C822O26-KMIX | -KMIX
9L47-C822M26-BFX  | -BFX
6L47-C822N27-GLKX | -GLKX

Using functions listed below only
Left, right,mid, Len, find, search and trim

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: It looks like instead of looking for the second `-` you're trying to find `| -` and the text after that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on ***Microosft-365*** then could try-

```
=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A2,"-"),,-1)
```

For Excel-2013 and later use `FILTERXML()`.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

For all version-

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

[image]

Comment: Lots of functions used not included in the OP's list. May have been a reason the OP specified those...

Answer (score 1):

These are true old-school spreadsheet methods:

**Search, Len, Right, Trim**:
`=TRIM(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2))-(SEARCH("-",A2,(SEARCH("-",A2))+1))+1))`

**Find, Len, Mid, Trim**:
`=TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1),(LEN(A2))-(FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1))+1))`

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

### After the 2nd Occurrence of a Dash Inclusively

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1)+1)
```

To prevent `#VALUE!` when not enough dashes, you could use `IFERROR`...

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1)+1),"")
```

... or for even older versions of Excel, you could use...

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",A3,FIND("-",A3)+1)),"",RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("-",A3,FIND("-",A3)+1)+1))
```

... revealing the importance of the expression `FIND("-",A3,FIND("-",A3)+1)`, the position of the 2nd occurrence.

Comment: Sorry earlier didnt see OP needed the "-" in the beginning --> `="-"&TEXTAFTER(A2,"-",-1)` & `="-"&RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","|",2),LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","|",2)))`

Answer (score 0):

Use find() like so:

```
=find("-",A1,find("-",A1,1)+1)
```

The inner find will return the position of the first "-" and the plus 1 makes the outer find look for the second.

Then use that result in MID() like so:

```
=mid(A1,find("-",A1,find("-",A1,1)+1)+1,100)
```

which will bring back 100 characters after the second "-".

Luckily mid() and find() are just about version independent AND they are in the list of functions you listed.

Answer (score 0):

```
=MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1),LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2)+1)+1)
```

Comment: That's basically what I posted an hour ago.

Comment: @RohitGupta A code-only answer is still an answer. It might be downvote-worthy, but it does not mean you should choose to delete it in a review queue.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, the reason for flagging for deletion was that it just repeats a previous answer as pointed out by Solar Mike.  I verified that before flagging it.

Comment: @RohitGupta That is 1) not a sufficient reason to delete (given both answers were posted on the same day, and the answers are different), 2) even if it were a valid reason, then the comment you used does not apply.

Comment: There is a significant difference in this answer finding the length of the cell, vs the previous answer using a fixed length of 100 characters.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have deleted my comment